# how to changes arrays , objects or xml to json feed?

Tags: json, dictionary, tree

I am trying to generate JSON feed from objects for Jit treemap .

Is there any way where i can convert objects to custom json. preferable using jquery.

I want to convert any objects and xml feed to JSOn so it works in this treemap
http://www.jquery4u.com/json/15-jquery-json-plugins/